# amazon s3 bucket upload from node code just stopped working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I literally didn't change anything to my code that handles the upload and it just all of a sudden stopped working.

it's running this code succesfully and not throwing an error -

```
s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', options, function(err, data) {
        if (err) return res.send('Error with S3')

        res.json({
            signed_request: data,
            url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/' + S3_BUCKET + '/' + fileID
        })
```

but then when I go to check my uploads it's not there. I haven't changed permissions, policies, anything. My access key and secret key are definitely correct. I can still access the links to the images I've already uploaded but the new ones are not being added.

Comment: okay this is SO weird. So I noticed my computer's clock wasn't the correct time so i turned the auto-time set on and off, now all of a sudden my s3 is working again o_O

Comment: nevermind.. i fixed the time and one upload worked then after that it stopped working again.. no idea if the events are related

Comment: It seems to randomly be working sometimes.. then it just stops working after 1 or 2 uploads